# struts2 evaluate empty string

Tags: string, struts2, evaluate

I have jsp file to display error message in

depends on whether the error string is empty or not.

```
 <s:if test="{!''.equals(errorMsg)}">
  <div class="errors"><s:property value="errorMsg"/></div>
 </s:if>
```

But whatever errorMsg is, the div section always there, why? how can solve this problem?

Comment: are you sure you don't actually want the actionerror tag (http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/actionerror.html) ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `!=`:

```
<s:if test='%{errorMsg != ""}'>
    ...
```

Although if it can be null, you should check for that as well (the reference itself will be `false` if it's null).

You were constructing an immediate list containing the value of the conditional.

Either use `%{}` or leave it off altogether.

Note that you could add errors directly to the action as well.